# Issue implementing ajax from one partial to another partial within a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 controllers: Welcome (which handles the homepage) and Invitations (Which help people to create/manage invites). I am trying to have on the same `welcome.html.erb` both partials from Invitation view: `_form.html.erb` (for creating invitation) and `_results.html.erb` (to display the invites via Ajax on the same `welcome.html.erb` page). 
I also have have `create.js.erb` in the Invitation's view folder. 
The input work well but there is no live update. I still need to refresh the page. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong please?

`_form.html.erb` code is:

```
<h3 class="section_title"> Express meeting request IR </h3>
<div id="theform">
<%= simple_form_for invitation do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
  <%= f.label "Dest." %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:guest_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, {}, class: "selectpicker", title: "Choose recipient", multiple: true, data: {style: "form-control", size: "200", width: "100%"})  %>

  <br><br>
  <%= f.input :event_id %>
    <%= f.input :start %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :type_of_event %>
    <%= f.label "Memo" %> <br>
    <%= f.text_area :memo,  as: :text, class: "text_area_iro", rows: 5 %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-custom"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

`_result.html.erb` (certain header of the table removed) looks as:

```
<% @invitationsR.each do |invitation| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= find_name(invitation.user_id) %></td>
            <td><%= invitation.start %></td>
            <td><%= TypeEvenement.find_by(id: invitation.type_of_event).type_name %> </td>         </tr>
        <% end %>
```

`create.js.erb` looks as:

```
$("#theform").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>  'invitations/result', :locals => {:invitation => @invitation}) %>");
```

`Welcome.html.erb` looks like

```
<%= render :partial =>  'invitations/form', :locals => {:invitation => Invitation.new} %>
<%= render :partial =>  'invitations/result', :locals => {:invitations => @invitations} %>
```

The controller is as usual with plain new and create methods. 
  The create method is as follows:

```
def create
    @listmail = params[:invitation][:guest_id]
    @listmail = @listmail.join(' ').split

    @listmail.each do |v|
      @invitation = current_user.invitations.build(invitation_params)
      @invitation.guest_id = v
      puts(v)
      @invitation.save!
    end

    if @invitation.save
      redirect_to invitations_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end
```

Comment: could you please post your `create` method? And may be `_invitation.html.erb` file name would be `_result.html.erb`

Comment: Hi emu, Just corrected. Should I be adding something in the controler ? so far everything works fine (creation, etc) except the ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works to clear the form after the Ajax validation:

```
$("#result_partial").html("<%= j render partial: 'invitations/result', :locals => {:invitation => @invitation} %>");
$("#result2_partial").html("<%= j render partial: 'invitations/result2', :locals => {:invitation => @invitation} %>");

$("#theform").remove();
$('#invitation_form').html("<%= j render partial: 'invitations/form', :locals => {:invitation => Invitation.new}  %>");
```

Just do not forget to reset the select2 items with :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){$('#invitation_guest_id').select2({
        placeholder: "Contact name, list or company",
        minimumInputLength: 3
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some typos and missing points. 
In your create method you need to define a instance variable called `@invitations` which you will pass in the partial as a local variable in `create.js.erb` file:

```
def create
    ---- skip code ----
      @invitation.save!
    end

    @invitations = current_user.invitations # define this one 

    if @invitation.save
    ---- skip code ----

  end
```

Now that you define the variable, thus in `create.js.erb` file would be:

```
$("#theform").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>  'invitations/result', :locals => {:invitations => @invitations}) %>");
```

In `_result.html.erb`:

```
<% invitations.each do |invitation| %>
    ## Content
<% end %>
```

Comment: Should I add a remote :true to the form ? I see it is quite important

Comment: @Etienne, Yes you have to. Otherwise, there will be no ajax call. Or, you can create a ajax request manually.

Comment: Ok, could you help me on the wording for the remote :true in such case please?

Answer (score 2):

1 =>  Add remote `:remote=> true` to let form submit via ajax request.

```
<%= simple_form_for invitation, id: "invitation_form", :remote=> true do |f| %>
  ###Content
<%end%>
```

2 => wrap result partial within a separate id as: -

```
<%= render :partial =>  'invitations/form', :locals => {:invitation => Invitation.new} %>
<div id "result_partial">
  <%= render :partial =>  'invitations/result', :locals => {:invitations => @invitations} %>
</div>
```

3 => It's always good practice to use local variable (invitations instead of @invitations) in partial i.e

In `_result.html.erb`

```
<% invitations.each do |invitation| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= find_name(invitation.user_id) %></td>
    <td><%= invitation.start %></td>
    <td><%= TypeEvenement.find_by(id: invitation.type_of_event).type_name %> </td>  
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

4 => Refactor create action (i.e always use in which format you should respond in html or js)

```
def create
  @listmail = params[:invitation][:guest_id]
  @listmail = @listmail.join(' ').split

  @listmail.each do |v|
    @invitation = current_user.invitations.build(invitation_params)
    @invitation.guest_id = v
    puts(v)
    if @invitation.save!
      @invitations = current_user.invitations #get all invitations  including new invitations  that has been saved just now
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html{ redirect_to invitations_path }
        format.js { render :layout => false }
      end
    else
      window.location = "http://localhost:3000/invitations.new";
    end
  end
end
```

5 => After respond back

```
$('#invitation_form').[0].reset(); #reset form
$("#result_partial").html("<%= j render partial: 'invitations/result', :locals => {:invitation => @invitation}) %>"); #Refresh only results
```

Comment: HI Gabbar, I got to update without refreshing, but The _form.html.erb is replaced by the _result.html.erb partial in the welcome.html.erb. What I would like is when the user validate the _form partial, that it automatically refresh the invitation/result.html.erb partial within the homepage.html.erb.

Comment: @Etienne I understand that, and i made an update in the answer check the update answer, as i have given a id to form, and after submitting form it is being reset, and only results are refreshed and form fields are being reset, hope it's clear to you.

Comment: `$("#result_partial").html("<%= j render partial: 'invitations/result', :locals => {:invitation => @invitation} %>");
` alone now works to update the _reult partial, the first line to reset the _form partial still not working. Still looking.

Comment: @Etienne Sorry my bad, missed to add comma(',') , try this as correct syntax `<%= simple_form_for invitation, id: "invitation_form", :remote=> true do |f| %>` also you can reset form as its jquery method. any further help?

Comment: Hey Gabbar, It is ok, I fixed it when i read your code actuall. BUt still no chance for me on `$('#invitation_form').[0].reset();`

Comment: @Etienne Glad to know that, hopefully you understood how we should handle ajax form submission. let me know if you need any help. thanks :)

Comment: I am being told I can use `$(function() {
  $('#theform').on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    if($("#theform")[0].checkValidity()) {
      $.post("/echo/json/", $("#theform").serialize(),function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
        $("#theform")[0].reset();
      });
     }
     else window.console &&  console.log("invalid form");
   });
 });  ` to reset the form after validation. I tried puting it in a <SCRIPT></SCRIPT> tag, but no luck. also tried puting it in the create.js.erb still no luck. Do you happen  to have a view on this one pls?